# Using a shell script within applescript to remove certain lines and change carriage returns to linefeeds, if present

Tags: shell, sed, applescript

Is there an easy way using applescript to run a shell script that a) converts all carriage returns to unix linefeeds and then b) removes specific lines from the file?   I have an very nice apple script/applet set up that will save a copy of the file with the lines removed (and I can drop multiple files on the applet), but if there are carriage returns, it fails.

Here is the shell script portion of my apple script:

```
**do shell script "sed  -e '10,11d' -e '1,8d' " & thisFile & ">>" & donefile**
```

Can both needs be combined into one shell script?

I am an admitted noob and will be grateful for any help / education offered.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can convert carriage return (`\r`) to newlines (`\n`), you need to add a part like this:

```
sed -e 's/\r/\n/g'
```

But this will probably change the line numbers for the following `sed` command you already have in place.

So the way to piece the new part together with what you have is probably something like this:

```
do shell script "sed -e 's/\r/\n/g' " & thisFile & " | sed  -e '10,11d' -e '1,8d' ">>" & donefile
```

Here we first run the substitution of carriage return to linefeed on `thisfile` and then pipe the result to your sed command part from your question.

(**Disclaimer:** I have no clue about applescript I just copied from your question and I hope that the piping would work like this in applescript.)

Comment: FWIW, the `**` don't have anything to do with applescript. I suspect that they were an attempt to format the code here (e.g. **bold**) but the intended effect was obliterated by the standard `code` formatting here.